# Error when using the tikz package

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, miktex

When compiling a simple MWE like:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

I obtain an error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1102 \pgfdeclarearrow
                       {name=|<->|,   means={>[sep=0pt].|}}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.1102 \pgfdeclarearrow{n
                         ame=|<->|,   means={>[sep=0pt].|}}
You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
```

I just recently updated MiKTeX 2.9. This is what the pdf file contains:

[image]

Here is the list of files:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
    tikz.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.142)
     pgf.sty    2013/12/18 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.14)
  pgfrcs.sty    2013/12/20 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.28)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  pgfsys.sty    2013/11/30 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.47)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.25)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
supp-pdf.mkii
 ***********
```

---

### EDIT

Completely uninstalling MikTeX 2.9 and downloading and installing MiKTeX 2.9 rev. 2.9.5105 solved the issue. This post may be closed as too localized if needed. The probably could have been in the installation of the package `pgf` since running `\listfiles` produces the same output as above?

Comment: you presumably have a version mis-match, add `\listfiles` and see what you get. The pdf output is as expected from your log if you do not stop at the error, it's just arbitrary recovery action, typesetting the (intended) argument as text `|` `<` etc coming out as punctuation characters in OT1 encoding.

Comment: No error with your code here with a MiKTeX updated yesterday, what included also the update to pgf/TikZ 3.0.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle updated with list of files.

Comment: I updated texlive this weekend but it still has v2.10 you have 3.0 but I guess the update is incomplete @Speravir could you say if your tikz 3 generated \listfiles is different to the above?

Comment: `\pgfdeclarearrow` is defined in `pgfcorearrows.code.tex`; do you find mention of this file in the `log` file?

Comment: @egreg yes. The log file contains:`(C:\Users\azetina\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcore
arrows.code.tex
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2008/04/23  (rcs-revision 1.11)
)`

Comment: I have `File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2013/11/07  (rcs-revision 1.40)` (in the same location as you). I suspect a bad installation by MiKTeX.

Comment: @egreg Any suggestions as to updating the tikz/pgf packages correctly? Should I connect to a different server when updating?

Comment: Sorry, but I know almost nothing about MiKTeX.

Comment: @egreg Its ok. I will run the files under TeXLive to see what happens but wanted the fix to this issue under MiKTeX as I usually use it more often.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the installation of an updated MiKTeX distribution solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**My suggestion:** Remove package `pgf` from MiKTeX with Package Manager and reinstall. There must be a flaw in your installation.

*Too long for a comment.*

I do not observe an error with MiKTeX 2.9, which was updated yesterday and does contain the update to pgf/TikZ 3.0.

File list for compilation of example code with `\listfiles`:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
    tikz.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.142)
     pgf.sty    2013/12/18 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.14)
  pgfrcs.sty    2013/12/20 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.28)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  pgfsys.sty    2013/11/30 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.47)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.25)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
supp-pdf.mkii
 ***********
```

Interestingly the compilation with TeX Live produces (apart from a difference of `graphics.cfg`, noticed by David Carlisle) some more entries below `supp-pdf.mkii`:

```
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
[…]
supp-pdf.mkii
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 ***********
```

Comment: Reinstalling the package made no difference. I even restarted my computer to see if that helps but no good results so far. I honestly do not understand what is the problem.

Comment: @azetina: I’m clueless, too.

Comment: The thing is that before the update, everything compiled perfectly. Don't know what to do? Is there like a revert button? Compiling on TeXLive gives no such errors

Comment: @azetina: Perhaps the package file on the mirror you use is partly defunct?

Comment: Which mirror do you use?

Comment: @azetina: I am in Germany, so a German one.